# Batch File: ( was unexpected at this time

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I am getting this error:

> ( was unexpected at this time

The error occurs after accepting the value of `a`. I tried and checked for null values that could cause such a problem,, but was unsuccessful.

```
echo off
cls
title ~USB Wizard~
echo What do you want to do?
echo 1.Enable/Disable USB Storage Devices.
echo 2.Enable/Disable Writing Data onto USB Storage.
echo 3.~Yet to come~.

set "a=%globalparam1%"
goto :aCheck
:aPrompt
set /p "a=Enter Choice: "
:aCheck
if "%a%"=="" goto :aPrompt
echo %a%

IF %a%==2 (
title USB WRITE LOCK
echo What do you want to do?
echo 1.Apply USB Write Protection
echo 2.Remove USB Write Protection
::param1
set "param1=%globalparam2%"
goto :param1Check
:param1Prompt
set /p "param1=Enter Choice: "
:param1Check
if "%param1%"=="" goto :param1Prompt

if %param1%==1 (
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies\ /v WriteProtect /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 
echo USB Write is Locked!
)
if %param1%==2 (
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies\ /v WriteProtect /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000
echo USB Write is Unlocked! 
)
)
pause
```

Comment: If you turn echo on (first line), do you see something helpful?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are getting that error because when the `param1` if statements are evaluated, param is always null due to being scoped variables without delayed expansion.

When parentheses are used, all the commands and variables within those parentheses are expanded.  And at that time, param1 has no value making the if statements invalid.  When using delayed expansion, the variables are only expanded when the command is actually called.

Also I recommend using `if not defined` command to determine if a variable is set.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
title ~USB Wizard~
echo What do you want to do?
echo 1.Enable/Disable USB Storage Devices.
echo 2.Enable/Disable Writing Data onto USB Storage.
echo 3.~Yet to come~.

set "a=%globalparam1%"
goto :aCheck
:aPrompt
set /p "a=Enter Choice: "
:aCheck
if not defined a goto :aPrompt
echo %a%

IF "%a%"=="2" (
    title USB WRITE LOCK
    echo What do you want to do?
    echo 1.Apply USB Write Protection
    echo 2.Remove USB Write Protection

    ::param1
    set "param1=%globalparam2%"
    goto :param1Check
    :param1Prompt
    set /p "param1=Enter Choice: "
    :param1Check
    if not defined param1 goto :param1Prompt
    echo !param1!

    if "!param1!"=="1" (
        REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies\ /v WriteProtect /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 
        echo USB Write is Locked!
    )
    if "!param1!"=="2" (
        REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies\ /v WriteProtect /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000
        echo USB Write is Unlocked! 
    )
)
pause
endlocal
```

Comment: "%var%"=="expected"

Answer (score 16):

Oh, dear. A few little problems...

As pointed out by others, you need to quote to protect against empty/space-containing entries, and use the !delayed_expansion! facility.

Two other matters of which you should be aware:

First, `set/p` will assign a user-input value to a variable. That's not news - but the gotcha is that pressing `enter` in response will leave the variable UNCHANGED - it will not ASSIGN a zero-length string to the variable (hence deleting the variable from the environment.) The safe method is:

```
 set "var="
 set /p var=
```

That is, of course, if you don't WANT `enter` to repeat the existing value.
Another useful form is

```
 set "var=default"
 set /p var=
```

or

```
 set "var=default"
 set /p "var=[%var%]"
```

(which prompts with the default value; `!var!` if in a block statement with delayedexpansion)

Second issue is that on some Windows versions (although W7 appears to "fix" this issue) ANY label - including a `:: comment` (which is a broken-label) will terminate any 'block' - that is, parenthesised compound statement)

Comment: +1 Great point about the hack label comments.  Here is an interesting discussion about the weird label comment behavior here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4204

Comment: @David Interesting discussion, but I'd reject the idea that `::` is a failed logged-drive switch. If it was, it should gnerate an error outside of a block. Whereas the academic argument may be interesting, sadly the rules and regulations regarding positioning of labels/::-comments  appear beyond the attention-span of today's average or casual batcher and the potential for breakage during maintenance makes "clever" usage too dangerous for my taste. Not sure whether the situation is version-dependent, either. I'll stick to a no-labels/::-comments-in-a-block philosophy for sanity's sake.

Comment: I agree with you.  Hack label comments should always be avoided inside parentheses due to their undefined behavior.  The discussion was just for those who wanted to read more about the behaviors and why it is bad to use them.

Comment: :: Comment within a for loop was my problem.  This was the first item that came up in my search.  Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

you need double quotes in all your three `if` statements, eg.:

```
IF "%a%"=="2" (
```

---

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cls
title ~USB Wizard~
echo What do you want to do?
echo 1.Enable/Disable USB Storage Devices.
echo 2.Enable/Disable Writing Data onto USB Storage.
echo 3.~Yet to come~.


set "a=%globalparam1%"
goto :aCheck
:aPrompt
set /p "a=Enter Choice: "
:aCheck
if "%a%"=="" goto :aPrompt
echo %a%

IF "%a%"=="2" (
    title USB WRITE LOCK
    echo What do you want to do?
    echo 1.Apply USB Write Protection
    echo 2.Remove USB Write Protection
    ::param1
    set "param1=%globalparam2%"
    goto :param1Check
    :param1Prompt
    set /p "param1=Enter Choice: "
    :param1Check
    if "!param1!"=="" goto :param1Prompt

    if "!param1!"=="1" (
         REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies\ /v WriteProtect /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001
         USB Write is Locked!
    )
    if "!param1!"=="2" (
         REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies\ /v WriteProtect /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000
         USB Write is Unlocked!
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a great answer!

Comment: @Endoro Your answer solved my problem which took many hours of my time. Thak you!

Comment: Can someone explain why this solution works??

Comment: Technically, it works because the two operands of the equality cannot expand to nothing anymore. It is not necessary to use double quotes specifically, you could as well use X or any other unproblematic string: IF X%a%==X

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error on your IF statement check if used or not your double equals to compare your variable.

Eg.

```
IF [%checkresult%]=1 GOTO INVALID
```

This throws "=1 was unexpected at this time."

To correct this add another equals sign.

```
IF [%checkresult%]==1 GOTO INVALID
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that same error using Netbeans as my IDE. I realized that my base folder in Windows had (1) imbedded in the path of my project, this happened when I copied the original zip file causing the (1) to be added to the file which in turn was blowing up the build process.

My fix,

1. close the project
2. Close IDE
3. Clean up path name for project, remove any funny characters
4. reimport project and build